# How to create a custom javascript in-bulit apply method

Tags: javascript

Lets consider this example:-

```
function X(){
     var Y = function(arg1,arg2){
              document.write(arguments.length);
              document.write(arg2);
              };
     Y(arguments);
}

x(1,2,3,4,5); 
/*Outputs  1 and undefined respectively. 
  Because here i am actually passing an array like-object  to Y. */
```

**By using apply here i am getting the desired results.**

```
function X(){
     var Y = function(arg1,arg2){
              document.write(arguments.length);
              document.write(arg2);
              };
     Y.apply(this,arguments);
}

x(1,2,3,4,5) //outputs 5 and 2
```

I want to create an **apply like method** that takes an Array of argument and invoke that function by passing arguments as seperate parameter values.

Like:

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4];
Y.apply_like_method(arr);
//and returns like Y(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question... why can't you just use `apply`?

Comment: @JamesAllardice i can but i just want to know how this apply method is coded..

Comment: @RobinsGupta: It's not implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: There's no alternative to `.apply()` afaik.

Comment: @RobinsGupta: Here's how it's implemented in V8, which is Chrome's JavaScript engine: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/runtime.cc#8608

Comment: [There you go](http://jsfiddle.net/CTjmF/).

Answer (score 1):

Given this code:

```
var arr=[1,2,3,4];
Y.apply_like_method(arr);
//and returns like Y(1,2,3,4)
```

To make that work:

```
Function.prototype.apply_like_method = function(args) {
    return this.apply(this, args);
}
```

***Disclaimer:** For illustration purposes only.*

In other words, there's no way around `.apply()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for shits and giggles using eval.

```
function myApply(fun, ar){
  var i, r = [];
  for(i=0; i<ar.length; ++i)
    r[i] = 'ar['+i+']';
  eval('fun('+r.join(',')+');');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the call method instead.  [See the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).   What you are describing though is a hybrid of the call method and apply method; you want the ability to supply parameters individually, but to supply them to the function as an array.  That, to my knowledge, doesn't exist currently and it would be easier to use apply/call as it was originally intended, or use a javascript object to pass the params into the function.

Comment: If you use Product as constructor, why you added return statement? and I think, that your answer is not related to the question.

Comment: That was an MDN example, as I noted.  he wants to use call/apply hybrid essentially.